# e.target.previousSibling.textContent dentro de iteración .forEach devuelve un string vacio

Tags: javascript, bucles, foreach

Estoy tratando de hacer un carrito de compras, tengo en el HTML tres elemento span con el precio y tres botones que deberían loguear en la consola el textContent del elemento que le precede (span).

Selecciono los botones con document.querySelectorAll, consiguiendo un NodeList, luego, con el método forEach agrego un eventListener al event.target para console.log el textContent del hermano anterior (previousSibling) del botón cliqueado.

El problema es que se loguea un string vacío con tres espacios ("   ") y no el precio. Si intento con innerHTML en vez del precio, se loguea 'undefined'.

Creo que es más fácil hacerlo con un loop pero me parece que con forEach se logra un código un poco más limpio y breve.

el html:

```
<div class="card">
  <h2 class="name">Galleta</h2>
  <img class="img" src="#">
  <p class="description">Linda galletita</p>
  <span class="price">$10</span>
  <button class="btn">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

el js:

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.previousSibling.textContent)
  })
})
```

la consola:

```
"
  "
```

el CodePen

https://codepen.io/luissimosa25/pen/PojQmOX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sustituye **previousSibling** por **previousElementSibling**

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! funcionó perfecto.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución,sería de más ayuda la respuesta a la comunidad si agregaras en que consiste el cambio, revisa [answer], saludos.

Comment: Investigué un poco y al parecer `.previousSibling` devuelve un objeto que representa al elemento anterior, ese objeto contiene información como el previousElement, parentElement, entre otros.

En cambio `.previousElementSibling` devuelve solamente el nodo como un elemento.

Es decir: `console.log(previousSibling)` devuelve un objeto, cuando `console.log(previousElementSibling)` devuelve, en este caso `<span class="price">$10</span>.`

Comment: Dejo un Pen, mirar la consola.

https://codepen.io/luissimosa25/pen/MWoQPYN